# How to prove that this infinite series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series in question is in the expression below. I know that the series converges but I am not sure how to prove so. I feel like there might be an infinite product involved, but we haven’t been taught that in my calculus class yet, so is there a different way to do it?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{2\cdot 5\cdot 8\cdots(3n+2)}.$$

Comment: What criteria do you know?

Comment: Using the ratio test you get $1/3$ which is less than $1$. Thus, you have convergence.

Comment: We’ve learned about some common tests to prove convergence, such as the n-th term, p-series, geometric series, alternating series, comparison test, limit comparison test, integral test, ratio test, and root test

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the limit of the ratio
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{3(n+1)+2}.$$
and use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac{k}{3k+2}<\frac{1}{2},$$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{k!}{2\cdot...\cdot(3k+2)}<\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=1$$